# Can I use printComponent without having to draw component to screen first?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have been using the `printComponent` that was shown in another question. It works great for printing a `JPanel` if I first add that `JPanel` to a `JFrame` and draw that `JFrame` to screen. But if I don't do that before I print, I get a blank page printed. Why is this?

Comment: Anton, what do u mean draw to a graphic object? sorry i am a noob to this graphics stuff.

Savvas Dalkitsis, If I set a prefered size for the panel would that cause it to work?

Comment: Preferred size is a suggestion to the Layout manager. So it wouldn't work. Also about the Graphics Object you can get it from a component by calling for instance new JPanel().getGraphics(); When working with swing components you can safely cast it to a Graphics2D object which provides more tools. Read the Java tutorial for further info on the Java2D API

Comment: I'm a bit confused now on what is causing your problem. Are you saying that drawing the JFrame then adding the JPanel does not display anything even if you paint it again after adding the JPanel?

Comment: he is trying to print a JPanel to a sheet of paper on the printer. And when passing it without having set it to setVisible(true) it prints blank.

Answer (score 3):

I've used code like the following to create a BufferedImage on a panel that is not visible on the frame:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
...  // add components
panel.setSize(300, 300);
panel.doLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because the panel you wish to draw has an initial size of 0,0. Once added to a container with a layout manager and is displayed, then it gets its "normal" size.

Comment: is there any way I can set this to have a size? i tried giving the panel a preferredsize but that didnt work.

Comment: try setSize(int width, int height). I'm not sure this will work since Java may still not draw the component but you can try.